# Deciding whether $(ax+b)/(cx+d)$ is increasing

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

In order of studying usual function such us :

1) $f(x)=ax^2$

2) $g(x)=\frac{a}{x}$

3) $h(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$

4) $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

To know if a function is increasing or decreasing we can calculate :

$T(a,b)=\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$

But for exemple in the function h(x) why do we calculate just  $bc-ad$.
Without using $T(a,b)$ ?

What about other functions ?

Answer (score 1):

this comes from the first derivative of $h(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ this is $$h'(x)=\frac{ad-bc}{(cx+d)^2}$$